# How to add the cross in a form admin to add an object with django

Tags: python, django

This is my custom **django** form in admin  :

```
class Rent_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    seller = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Seller.objects.order_by('name'))
    norm = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,queryset=Norm.objects.order_by('name'),required=False)
    equipment = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Equipment.objects.order_by('name'),required=False)
    pic = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Pic.objects.order_by('name'),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Rent
        fields = '__all__'
```

But in the admin view i don't see the green cross to add an object near all my customs form.

How to add the green cross to add object with my form ?

Regards

Edit :

I've tried this :

```
import django.contrib.admin.widgets

class MyRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
    """
    This class is a wrapper to a given widget to add the add icon for the
    admin interface.
    """
    def render(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        rel_to = self.rel.to
        info = (rel_to._meta.app_label, rel_to._meta.model_name)
        self.widget.choices = self.choices
        output = [self.widget.render(name, value, *args, **kwargs)]
        if self.can_add_related:
            related_url = reverse(
                'admin:%s_%s_add' 
                % info, current_app=self.admin_site.name
            )
            output.append(
            """
            <a  href="%s"
                onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);
                alt="%s">

                <i class="help icon-large icon-plus-sign"
                    id="add_id_%s"
                    data-original-title>
                </i>
            </a>""" % (related_url, _('Add Another'), name))
            return mark_safe(''.join(output))

# Monkeypatch it
django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper = MyRelatedFieldWidgetWrapper

class Rent_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    seller = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Seller.objects.order_by('name'))
    norm = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,queryset=Norm.objects.order_by('name'),required=False)
    equipment = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Equipment.objects.order_by('name'),required=False)
    pic = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Pic.objects.order_by('name'),required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Rent
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Rent_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['norm'].widget = django.contrib.admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper()
```

But i have a :

```
__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'widget', 'rel', and 'admin_site'
```

Error

Comment: You need to wrap the widgets in `admin.widgets.RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How to do that ? I've triied somethiong but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here. Why are you monkeypatching the existing admin class?

Comment: I'am trying to add the cross by monkey matching

Comment: But why? That class *already* adds the cross, that's the point. You should just need to wrap your own widgets with that class.

Comment: How to do that ?